# What should the proper way of overriding of fnClick for PDF button look like? (JS, Datatable, Datatables-tools)

Tags: javascript, pdf, coffeescript, datatables

It works completly fine for copy, XLS, CSV, but not for PDF.
Below a piece of coffeescript:

```
tableToolsOptions:
        sSwfPath: "/static/external/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        sRowSelect: 'multi'
        sSelectedClass: 'row_selected'
        bHeader: true
        aButtons: [
            {
                sExtends: 'collection',
                sButtonText: '<i class="icon-wrench"></i> <span class="caret" />',
                aButtons: [
                        sExtends: 'xls'
                        sFileName: '*.xls'
                        mColumns: 'visible'
                        bHeader: false
                        bFooter: false
                        bSelectedOnly: true
                        fnClick: (nButton, oConfig, oFlash) ->
                            table_with_headers = $(this.dom.table).find("thead tr th").map(->
                              $(this).text()
                            ).get().join("\t")
                            table_with_headers += "\n#{this.fnGetTableData(oConfig)}"
                            this.fnSetText(oFlash, table_with_headers )
                    ,
                        sExtends: 'pdf'
                        mColumns: 'visible'
                        bHeader: false
                        bFooter: false
                        bSelectedOnly: true
                        fnClick: (nButton, oConfig, flash) ->
                            table_with_headers = $(this.dom.table).find("thead tr th").map(->
                              $(this).text()
                            ).get().join("\t")
                            table_with_headers += "\n#{this.fnGetTableData(oConfig)}"
                            console.log table_with_headers
                            this.fnSetText(flash, table_with_headers )
```

I would appriciate some hint.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF one has to pass some more parameteres.
instead of raw:

```
this.fnSetText(flash, table_with_headers )
```

use something like:

```
this.fnSetText( flash, "colWidth:#{this.fnCalcColRatios(oConfig)}\norientation:#{oConfig.sPdfOrientation}\nsize:#{oConfig.sPdfSize}\n--/TableToolsOpts--\n #{table_with_headers}")
```